# How do i convert 5 click functions into one with changes values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I convert 5 click functions into one? eg

```
$("div#styleswitcher a.green").click(function () {
    $("container").css({ 'background': 'green' });
});

$("div#styleswitcher a.blue").click(function () {
    $("container").css({ 'background': 'blue' });
});

$("div#styleswitcher a.red").click(function () {
    $("container").css({ 'background': 'red' });
});

$("div#styleswitcher a.yellow").click(function () {
    $("container").css({ 'background': 'yellow' });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

This comes to mind:

```
$("#styleswitcher a").click(function ()
{
    $("container").css("background-color", this.className);
});
```

Assumption is that the background color should be the class name, as in your example